# Figuring out why MAAS cannot connect to virsh

Tags: maas, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to get MAAS to talk to virsh on localhost to not have to configure a whole extra physical machine to run deployment service juju on. MAAS seems to be able to deploy a virtual machine to this extent and the host it's running on is more than capable of meeting the requirements (seems to be 4GB of RAM, which it has 20 of).

In MAAS, I go to the tab *KVM*, set the *Name* as `local_kvm`,  leave *Zone*, *Resource Pool*, and *Password (optional)* as default, and set the *Address* to either of

```
qemu+ssh://root@localhost/system
qemu:///system
```

In both cases: It's failing with the very unhelpful error message:

```
Failed talking to pod: Failed to login to virsh console.
```

Directly running:

```
virsh -c <address>
```

succesfully connects to the local virsh console after accepting/trusting *127.0.0.1* as a host. Of course, thinking that perhaps the MAAS gui doesn't 'force' the SSH connection through if it does not recognize/trust the host, I try again with the MAAS GUI, yet after doing so trying to do so in the GUI again fails with the same error message.

Which just states 'it failed', but doesn't really tell me **why**. Here's what I'd like to know:

- What **user** is this being executed as?
- What **command** is MAAS trying to execute?
- Where can I find a **log file** containing detailed reasons as to why the qemu/ssh connection failed?
- Is it possible that this error message is printed *regardless* of what went wrong, because I haven't configured storage, networks, etc. yet for KVM/libvirt-qemu, apart from removing DHCP from it.

Note that I already installed qemu on the host, running plain `virsh` on the terminal as root works.

A lot of the instructions online refer to a *maas* user, yet I do not have this user on the machine. The thing was installed via *apt* as the root account, and the services appear to run as such, on **root**. Perhaps it shouldn't, to make things work, but then the question becomes: how do I change it not to do this, while not completely breaking it, as I'd imagine lots of necessary (virtual) files are owned by root that would need to be changed?

Comment: I am running into this as well. Further, if I manually create the VM over SSH on the MAAS host and bring it up with PXE boot and set the power mode to virsh, then the connection string fails there as well.  I was able to find this, but it doesn't seem to help (it shouldn't really make a difference if you are using localhost):  https://discourse.maas.io/t/2-6-solved-deploy-fail-failed-to-login-to-virsh-console/1002/2  Are using the ubuntu PPA for MAAS?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue.  Initially, I had installed the snap, but then after running into permissions issues, I decided to switch to the PPA `apt` installation, which wasn't straight forward given that the project is working towards doing away with it.  The following is what got me to success.

1. Uninstall the snap if it's installed.
2. [Install the PPA](https://discourse.maas.io/t/non-snap-maas-installs/1308), but don't install `latest`, instead use a version (just as the guide describes). This will also add the `maas` user. Version 2.9 worked for me.
3. Follow these two nearly identical guides, bridging gaps when one or the other falls short: [maas.io guide](https://maas.io/tutorials/create-kvm-pods-with-maas) and [an unofficial guide](https://technology.amis.nl/platform/kubernetes/charmed-kubernetes-on-kvm-using-maas-and-juju/).
4. You should now have a working MAAS install with all of the extra configuration that will be required to get this working. Of the two guides, you'll eventually get to this command in one of them where you add the `maas` user to the `libvirt` group: `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt maas`. If you execute that command, then the `maas` user will have access to libvirt, and will be able to execute `virsh` commands locally with the connection string set to `qemu:///system`.  This is my setup, (the MAAS server is also the KVM server).
5. If you prefer to use a different user to manage the VMs in MAAS, then add the user to the libvirt group instead of `maas`, then follow the other guide on creating an SSH key and copying it over.  If you want something more succinct, you can look at [this example](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-configure-maas-to-be-able-to-boot-virtual-machines/) which is also how you might setup a VM that's been manually created on a non-configured or manual KVM host.  This is also how you would configure an alternate host to manage the VMs.

While it seems they are moving away from supporting the PPA, another option all together may be to run MAAS in an `lxd` container.  I'll be heading this route if I ever need to upgrade, and you can find documentation on that [here](https://discourse.maas.io/t/install-with-lxd/757).